# How to restore formState in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I have a simple form with usage `react-final-form`. This form automatically saved each time when `values` changed. When the user reloads the page for some reason, the form gets initialValues from the previous saved values. Its work well, but `meta.pristine` and other properties from `meta` not saved. Is it possible to restore `formState` in `react-final-form`?

Comment: try this https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/46#issuecomment-351748234

Comment: i am not need reset values, but i want save the formState on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a thing that persists **all** the form state across refreshes? I've been maintaining form libs for years and I hadn't heard of this feature request. This is, of course, not the way The Web normally works. Seems *possible*, but it will require some more thought. [Submit an issue](https://github.com/final-form/final-form/issues/new) to Final Form requesting this.

The official answer as of the time of this post is: No, this is not supported yet.

Comment: Thank you, for answer. I created a new issue on GitHub https://github.com/final-form/final-form/issues/312